# Change the Date of a Review in Magento

Tags: magento

Magento reviews follow this format:-

- Summary
- Body of Review
- Date of Review

I need to change the date of the review to a custom date.

Please could somebody guide me on how to go about doing this? I have tried editing the review in the back-end, but the only sections I can change are the Summary and the Body of the review.

If you could let me know where in the database I should change, I'd really appreciate it. Or, if there is a way to change this in the back-end, without installing an extension, that'd be really awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

The Magento Admin backend does not have a place to edit the date of a product review. You must do this **directly in the SQL database** or **programmatically**.

The following instructions will help you change it *directly in the SQL database*.

---

### 1.) Find The Review ID

Login to your Magento backend Admin area and go here in the menu:

Magento Admin >> Catalog >> Reviews and Ratings >> Customer Reviews >> All Reviews

In the resulting table of **all reviews**, find the single review you want to change the date for.  Do not click into the review because the ID is only shown in the table of all reviews.

**Remember that ID**

---

### 2.) Change the Date in the Database

I used ***PhpMyAdmin*** to get access to my Magento SQL database. You can use whatever SQL Management Platform suits you.

1. Login to your SQL database and navigate the the table named only '**review**'.
2. In that table you will see a column called '**review_id**'.
3. Find the row in the '**review.review_id**' column that matches the ID of the review you want to change the Magento date for.
4. Click '**Edit**' on that row and change the '**created_at**' value of it.
5. Save your changes to the row by clicking '**Go**'.

**You're done.**

Check Magento to make sure it displays the updated date.

---

### Helpful Hints

- The date value in '**created_at**' must be in the format of an SQL date-time. This is '***YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss***'.
- Magento is sensitive to timezones. You may need to adjust the date value you use to compensate for this - so it displays the way you want it.
- The SQL '**review**' table was not listed on my first page of table names in PhpMyAdmin.  To find it, I had to click through to the second page of table names.
- It is very easy to ruin your website by clicking the wrong things in PhpMyAdmin.  So don't screw around in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think by **directly manipulating** the **reviews** details from **Databaes**. Although this seems to be discouraged but since it may be one or two records, then creating a custom solution is not feasible.

Running this MySQL to fetch the reviews info from the DB may help you locate the review you are trying to edit.

```
SELECT 
  rd.`detail_id`,
  rd.`review_id`,
  r.`created_at`,
  rd.`title`,
  rd.`detail`,
  rd.`nickname`,
  r.`review_id` 
FROM
  `review_detail` rd 
  LEFT JOIN review r 
    ON rd.`review_id` = r.`review_id` 
ORDER BY rd.`detail_id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set all Magento 1.x reviews to the order created date us this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE review r INNER JOIN review_detail rd ON (rd.review_id = r.review_id AND r.entity_id = 1) INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item oi ON (oi.product_id = r.entity_pk_value) INNER JOIN sales_flat_order as o ON (o.entity_id = oi.order_id) SET r.created_at = o.created_at;

SELECT r.review_id, r.created_at as review_date, o.created_at as order_date, o.increment_id, oi.sku FROM review r INNER JOIN review_detail rd ON (rd.review_id = r.review_id AND r.entity_id = 1) INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item oi ON (oi.product_id = r.entity_pk_value) INNER JOIN sales_flat_order as o ON (o.entity_id = oi.order_id) GROUP BY oi.product_id ORDER BY r.created_at DESC;

COMMIT;
```

Tested and verified on Magento 1.9.x